# Flask-SQLalchemy - Get a relationship argument from a Parent class in a Sub class

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using SQLalchemy and Flask-SQLAlchemy, I'm able to set up the following *User* class and sub classes *Customer* and *Provider* :

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=False)
    user_type = Column(String(32), nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_on':'user_type',
    'polymorphic_identity':'user_type'
    }


class Customer(User):
    __tablename__ = "customer"
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    note_customer = Column(Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity':'customer'
    }

class Provider(User):
    __tablename__ = "provider"
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    note_provider = Column(Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity':'provider'
    }


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    number = Column(Integer)
    street = Column(String(100))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship(User)
```

Then I am able to create a new customer :

```
u = Customer(name= 'Mark', user_type='customer', note_customer = 15)
db.session.add(u)
db.session.commit()
```

But I would like to add an address value to my *Customer Mark* during his creation and I don't succeed in and can't figure out how doing it.
I guess I'm wrong with my relationship : for me it's a "*one-to-one*" type, but many solutions I tried give me errors telling that the *address argument* is not available for a *Customer object type*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you neither use a [backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html) or explicitly create 2 back populating relationships. Because of this the `User` model class has no idea of the relationship and no `Address` instance can be passed to it or subclasses when constructing. The error you're receiving should be:

```
TypeError: 'address' is an invalid keyword argument for Customer
```

## Using [backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.backref) argument of [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship)

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    number = Column(Integer)
    street = Column(String(100))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship(User, backref=backref('address', uselist=False))
```

This creates a relationship attribute *address* on `User` model as if you'd added it manually:

```
    address = relationship('Address', uselist=False, ...)
```

You need to use a `backref()` object in order to pass `uselist=False` since you want a [one to one](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one) relationship.

## Using explicit relationship attributes

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=False)
    user_type = Column(String(32), nullable=False)

    address = relationship('Address', uselist=False, back_populates='user')

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    number = Column(Integer)
    street = Column(String(100))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship(User, back_populates='address')
```

The *back_populates* parameters will establish event listeners that will mirror attribute operations between the classes.

With a proper relationship configuration in place creating a new `Customer` with an address can be done like this:

```
u = Customer(name='Mark', user_type='customer', note_customer=15,
             address=Address(number=221, street='Baker Street'))
session.add(u)
session.commit()
```

or in separate steps:

```
u = Customer(name='Mark', user_type='customer', note_customer=15)
u.address = Address(number=221, street='Baker Street')
session.add(u)
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your customer class isn't defined to have an address.

You could simply add another few lines to put Mark's address in, and tie the relationship to Mark.

```
mark_address = Address(number='123', street='Main St', user = u)
db.session.add(mark_address)
db.session.commit()
```